# My local repository constantly says * branch develop -> FETCH_HEAD Already up-to-date

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-push, git-pull

When i try to git pull origin develop... the problem is I know it's not up-to-date. I want to pull everything to get back to where everything is up-to-date with others commits.

If i have nothing else of importance in my local repository can i just re-pull from origin develop? I'm thinking it will overwrite everything but at least than i'll be up-to-date and have the save version is everyone else!?!?!?

This was my original workflow with git but somehow everything got skewed:

```
git add files_that_were_updated
git commit -m "Message."
git push origin BUG-#
git checkout develop
git fetch origin
git pull origin develop
git merge BUG-#
git push origin develop
```

Seems pretty standard and straightforward, no?

Comment: Not really. What is the sense of pushing `BUG-#` just to merge it in right away? And if you `fetch`ed already, there is no reason to `pull`, but a simple `merge` is enough, as `pull` is `fetch`+`merge` or `fetch`+`rebase`, depending on your configuration and options. And btw. if you set up `origin/develop` as tracking branch for your local `develop` (probably is like that already) you don't need to tell where to push to or where to pull from.

Comment: What is the failed output?  Agreed, this sounds like it'll work.  You've got a few too many commands in there, but nothing that'll do harm.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to see which branch you were, when you executed the first commit, so it is possible that you made the commit directly to the `develop` branch, thinking that you were on the BUG-# branch. That would explain why you get the "Already up-to-date" message, given that your local `develop` is now ahead of the `develop` on the remote repository.

---

An easy way to be sure you get the latest branch from the remote repository (e.g. origin), down to your repository, is to do a `git fetch branchName:branchName --force`, whilst you are in a different branch than `branchName`.

In your example, something like this:

```
# assuming you are on branch `BUG-#`
git add files_that_were_updated
git commit -m "Message."
git push origin BUG-#
git fetch origin develop:develop --force
...
```

The last command above will replace your local `develop` branch with the `develop` branch that is on the server where your `origin` remote is pointing to.

Notice that, to be able to do that, you cannot be in the same branch that is being replaced, so always go to a different branch first.